# API Platform with alternative Runtime, Caddy, Vulcain, Cache ecosystem

Tags: varnish, http2, api-platform.com, caddy, swoole

Currently I'm investigating a setup backed by api-platform with the following goals:

- the PHP backend MUST yield minimal resource payloads, thus I do not want to embed relations at all
- the PHP backend SHOULD be able to run in alternative runtimes, e.g. Swoole
- the webserver should push related resources via HTTP2 Push leveraging the built in vulcain support of the api-platform distribution

I cannot find that many resources about those setups - at least not in such a form that they answer subsequent questions sufficiently.

My starting setup was simply based on the [api-platform distribution 2.6.8](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/releases/tag/v2.6.8)

So, until now I've learned the following things:

- out of the box, the caddy + http2 push setup works with the PHP container being based on `php:8.1-fpm-alpine` - while caddy is obviously directly using `php_fastcgi`
- when I was fooling around with the currently available [cache-handler](https://github.com/caddyserver/cache-handler) I was able to get the http cache working but I was struggling to find any information about cache invalidation works. The api-platform docs mostly focus on varnish; there is also only a `VarnishPurger` shipped in the api-platform core. Wring a custom one should not be that hard *if* the caddy cache-handler somehow allows `BAN` requests or something similar - where to find info about that? I see that the handler is based on [Souin](https://github.com/darkweak/souin) - but as unfamiliar as I am I have no clue how (and if) Souin supports cache invalidation after all.
- when changing the php container to be (in my current testing scenario) based on [Swoole](https://openswoole.com/) then `php_fastcgi` cannot be used in caddy - instead, I ended up using `reverse_proxy` (as described in [vulcain docs](https://github.com/dunglas/vulcain/blob/main/docs/caddy.md#configuration)) which basically works and serves proper http responses but does not push any resources requested with `Preload` headers (as I said, it worked when the PHP backend was based on PHP-FPM). How can I debug what happens here? Caddy does not yield any info about the `push` handling - nor does the vulcain caddy module

Long story short(er): to sum up my questions

- how can I figure out why caddy + vulcain is not working in a reverse_proxy setup?
- is the current state of the caddy cache handler functional / supported by the api-platform distribution
- how to implement/support `BAN` requests (or other fine grained cache invalidation) for caddy cache handler?

Comment: A while a go I created a pretty comprehensive (and official) `BAN` tutorial on the Varnish Developer Portal: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/ban/

Comment: @thijs-feryn thanks for your input - actually, the `BAN` for varnish is not the point in my thread, I've seen that working in the api-platform / varnish combo... it's more about the possibly missing or unknown `BAN` (or similar) for Souin on which the caddy cache-handler is based on

Comment: In the meanwhile I figured out that the issue of the failing Preload Pushes seems to be related to Swoole - I've checked a similar setup with Roadrunner and there it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Souin supports the invalidation using the `PURGE` HTTP method. I already wrote a PR to set Souin in the api-platform/core project but they are busy with the v3.0 release. Maybe in a near future they'll review and probably merge it, I dunno. But if you use a decorator on the varnish purger and use the code I wrote in the PR, you'll be able to purge automatically the associated endpoints to the base route.